# System restore will wipe other partitions

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I will restore my Windows 10 with "restore pc" tool, "erase all data" option. So my question is: Other partitions in my hard drive will be clean too? I want to keep files in them.

Comment: If system restore is something from your manufacturer, then the answer is yes. If you refer to "Reset this PC" feature in windows 10, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

No, Once you select to wipe data restore pc tool will ask to you if erase all or only windows partition.

Source: https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1266840-windows-10-reset-this-pc-will-it-delete-files-on-another-partition/

**Update**

keep in mind, it is always a good practice have a backup of the important data in a safe place (cloud storage, external disk) independently if you have to perform risk operation or not; I mean if you do not have a backup of your data, do it.